# Laravel pass json to vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5, vue.js

I'm using Laravel and I would like to pass json to my `new Vue` instance. How could I do this.

I pass the employees object like this:

```
 $employees = EmployeeModel::with('role','department.company')->get();
 return view('employees.employees')->with('employees',$employees);
```

Then in my new Vue I do it like this:

```
new Vue({
            el: 'body',
            data:{
                role: '',
                company: '',
                list:'{{ $employees }}',
                created() {
                    this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
                }
            }
        });
```

> It throws an error:vue.js:983 [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating
>   expression "CompanyName".

When I put the json manual into the list it works! So like this:

```
  new Vue({
                el: 'body',
                data:{
                    role: '',
                    company: '',
            list:[{"EmployeeId":1,"RoleId":5,"DepartmentId":6,"InternId":1,"FirstName":"Zoe","LastName":"Altenwerth","Bio":"Quidem perferendis.","email":"Kole.Bechtelar@hotmail.com","LinkedIn":"Sterling.Schowalter@example.net","Gender":0,"password":"$2y$10$bbUlDh2060RBRVHSPHoQSu05ykfkw2hGQa8ZO8nmZLFFa3Emy18gK","PlainPassword":"gr^S=Z","remember_token":"D528C0Ba1Xzq3yRV7FdNvDd8SYbrM0gAJdFUcOBq4sNEJdHEOb2xIQ0geVhZ","Address":"0593 Dallin Parkway Apt. 499\nBotsfordborough, MT 12501","Zip":"21503-","City":"East Janiston","ProfilePicture":null,"BirthDate":"2002-10-13 00:00:00","StartDate":"1995-11-09 21:42:22","EndDate":"2011-01-27","Suspended":0,"created_at":"2016-02-29 12:21:42","updated_at":"2016-03-02 11:53:58","deleted_at":null,"role":{"RoleId":5,"RoleName":"Superadministrator","Description":"Mag administrators toevoegen en bewerken","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},"department":{"DepartmentId":6,"CompanyId":12,"DepartmentName":"com","Description":"Accusantium quae.","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-02-29 12:21:41","updated_at":"2016-02-29 12:21:41","company":{"CompanyId":12,"CompanyName":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Logo":null,"Address":"85762 Tabitha Lights\nWest Jettie, AK 20878-2569","Zip":"29601","City":"Traceside","KvKNumber":"84c70661-9","EcaboNumber":"fdee61e3-a22d-3332-a","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-02-29 12:21:41","updated_at":"2016-02-29 12:21:41"}}}]
                    created() {
                        this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
                    }
                }
            });
```

So how can I pass the $employees object to my `new Vue` instance and use it?

Comment: What do you mean by "manual JSON"? That second example doesn't look like JSON...

Comment: @elclanrs yeah sorry about that I've changed that ^.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have to send your data as JSON. Try this:

```
 return view('employees.employees')->with('employees',json_encode($employees));
```

Comment: that's not the case. Because Laravel does that automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this, before declaring Vue.

```
var employees = {!!  json_encode($employees) !!};
```

then

```
 list: employees,
```

Comment: You probably still should escape string